# How do I distinguish between Cyclist and Bicycle classes using a CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, detection, yolov5

I am trying to train a CNN that is able to detect both `Cyclist` and `Bicycle` classes in images. In addition, I also want the model to detect `Person` objects. Currently I am trying with YOLO models, but when a cyclist appears in an image the model sometimes detects `Cyclist` and sometimes `Bicycle` and `Person`. **How can I make the model detect `Cyclist` correctly, without confusing it with a `Bicycle` and/or a `Person`?**

Many thanks for helping out here! :)